# switch statement optimization (Swift)

Tags: optimization, swift, switch-statement

In swift switch statements, does the condition get called once or for each case? Which would be faster?

```
switch foo(param) {
case 0:
    NSLog(0)
default:
    NSLog("default")
}
```

or

```
let myNumber = foo(param)    

switch myNumber {
case 0:
    NSLog(0)
default:
    NSLog("default")
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? There should not be any difference between the two.

Comment: You can easily test that yourself: Write a function `foo()` that prints some output when called.

Comment: this question is like _which would be faster: `while (1) {...}` or `while(2) {...}`?_...

Comment: not really, in for loops one should use a local variable instead of a function call each iteration

Comment: @quemeful, you have became an expert in this topic in one minute. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`switch` evaluates its argument only once.

As Martin suggested in the comments, this example proves it

```
func foo(name: String) -> Int {
  println(name)
  return countElements(name)
}

switch foo("hello") {
  case 0: println(0)
  case 1: println(1)
  default: println("default")
}
```

output

```
hello
default
```

In case it were evaluating for each case, you would expect

```
hello
hello
default
```

instead